# How to call a server side method with a parameter (an object) using ajax where the url has query params?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, post, webmethod

I need to call the server side method `MethodToBeCalledFromJS` from the client side. The ajax call needs a url which contains query parameters. Where do I put the method name in the ajax call?

This is the js code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx?queryParam1=value1&queryParam2=value2",
    data: "{ Param1: " + JSON.stringify(myObject) + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
    }
});
```

And I need to call the following function in C#

```
[WebMethod]
public string MethodToBeCalledFromJS(MyObject obj)
{
    return "successful!";
}
```

Comment: may be you are looking for dwr?

Answer (score 0):

Add MethodName in your URL

```
url: "MyPage.aspx/MethodToBeCalledFromJS?queryParam1=value1&queryParam2=value2",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx",
    data: { 'obj': JSON.stringify(myObject),
            'param2': 'myOtherValue'},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The method to call must be after aspx page name. You can pass parameters directly in `data`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx?MethodToBeCalledFromJS",
    data: "{ obj: " + JSON.stringify(myObject) + ", queryParam1: value1, queryParam2: value2 }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
    }
});
```

And then your method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string MethodToBeCalledFromJS(MyObject obj, string queryParam1, string queryParam2)
{
    return "successful!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need query parameters in the url, not as parameters to the called method.

Comment: Ok, but what's the motivation?

Comment: The query parameters are being used in various other methods in the cs file. Hence, I cannot make them local to this method.

Comment: And how you will get `queryParam1` value in `MethodToBeCalledFromJS`?